# How to create desktop application and store data online?

Tags: mysql, windows, desktop-application

I'm used to creating web apps. Using cpanel and mysql database. I am looking into creating desktop application with a similar web app concept with multiple users, login system and basic CRUD operations. In web app we simply host the website and use cpanel and mysql . How about in desktop application? what are the normal practices for creating a desktop application and storing data online(like cpanel's php myadmin)?

please advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer but Simple solution for lazy people like me. The best practice for this in my point of view is creating the desktop app via WebView for example if you want use java for the Desktop then there's WebView interface In JavaFx for webpages the WebView works like a browser it include HTML5 and CSS3 or Electron which is framework for creating Desktop app via web technologies. You can find more info about it.